# Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint; Error number: 2627; No duplicity in input data

Tags: c#, sql

I am trying to update my SQL database, but I am getting the error in title.

In the exception message I can find the duplicate key but I **can not find the same key in the input data**. What am I missing?

[image: I have made the program to write the exception message into console.]

Definition of the table is here:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MLFBCodes] 
(
    [Id]              INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [IdGroup]         INT           NOT NULL,
    [Number]          NVARCHAR(30)  NOT NULL,
    [Description]     NVARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
    [MLFB]            NVARCHAR(50)  NOT NULL,
    [Active]          BIT           NOT NULL,
    [UserDefined]     BIT           DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
    [ColumnForSearch] NVARCHAR(600) NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
    UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([Number] ASC),
    UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([MLFB] ASC),
    UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([Description] ASC),

    CONSTRAINT [FK_MLFBCodes_ToTable] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([IdGroup]) REFERENCES [dbo].[MLFBCodeGroups] ([Id])
);
```

This is what am I inserting:

[image]

There is no string "A5E037667170010EE0" which is returned from database as duplicated value (can see in the pic. from console above)

The foreach from the pic above:

```
foreach(MLFBCode code in mLFBsForAdd)
    try
    {
        db.MLFBCodes.Add(code);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
```

How can this happen? Thank you for help!

Comment: This, [still](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69935045/violation-of-unique-key-constraint-error-number-2627-no-duplicity-in-input-da), is not a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

you need to post the whole list of objects in order we could tell what is wrong, but you can do it without us. I can see 3 columns that should have an unique value

```
UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([Number] ASC),
UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([MLFB] ASC),
UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([Description] ASC),
```

you have to check  this columns in your list, they should be unique and non empty

IMHO I don't know what is Number or MLFB but it doesn't look as a good idea for me that Descrtiption column should have an unique constrant.

Comment: Unfortunately I cant post the whole list of inserted items but I think its not needed now. Maybe we dont understand to each other. My current problem is: Why the alleged duplicity from the database is "A5E037667170010EE0" when I dont insert this value at all?  The eample of inserted MLFBCode instance is in the picture above (MLFB: "3VA1112-4EE32-0BF0"; Number: "L1V30075125012"; Description: "MCCB_ST160_3P............"). And about the Description column: for us is better to make it unique because it wouldnt be logical to have two same descriptions.

Comment: @When you put an Unique constraint it means that ALL items in this column of the table should be unique. You can have this code or this number in data base already and it causes the error.

Comment: Yes, I understand what the Unique constraint is. But when I insert "A" then it cant tell me that I cant insert "B". It doesnt make a sence to me. I know that database already contains string "B" (I have found it) but I dont want to rewrite it, because i am inserting "A". Please be patient with me, I am not professional. Thank you :-)